# mpmath library magnitude of number bug?

Tags: python, debugging, mpmath

In [the documentation of mpmath library](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/mpmath.pdf) page 8 it mentioned that

> There is no restriction on the magnitude of numbers

```
>>> print(mpf(2)**32582657 - 1)
1.24575026015369e+9808357
```

and I checked that this code did work. However, in the same script I found that

```
mp.mpf(1e309)
mpf('+inf')
```

Is this a bug? How to set mpmath library to arbitrary magnitude of number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

In your first code snippet `mpf(2)**32582657` will dispatch into custom raise-to-power operator `**`, which will make use of the arbitrary precision functionality.

In your second code snippet `1e309` is a number literal, that will be parsed by the Python interpreter into a architecture native floating point number and 309 is an exponent to large to fit into the underlying IEEE754 format, before it even reaches `mpmath`

Instead, if you issued

```
mp.mpf(10)**309
```

you'd get the expected result

```
mpf('1.0e+309')
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct.